# Pass touch events from horizontal UICollectionView to vertical UITableView superview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UITableView` that scrolls vertically. In each cell, there is a `UICollectionView` which scrolls horizontally. I would like to make it so that the user can scroll the table view vertically, even while a horizontal collection view is being scrolled horizontally.

However, when I drag horizontally in the collection views, vertical motion is not passed on to the scrollview. How can I get the touch events in the collection views to the scroll view superview?

I've seen a bunch similar questions, but none that seem to address this specific issue -- most of them are concerned with getting scrolls from the superview to the subviews, and handle it in ways that aren't applicable here, like setting properties such as `delaysContentTouches`.